# Ikev2 vpn connection

Tags: networking, vpn, strongswan

I am on Fedora 31, I am trying to connect to a VPN that uses IKEv2 via strongswan. But I get `[IKE] received NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN notify the error.` I used the following tutorial https://www.securevpn.pro/eng/setup/linux-ikev2-vpn?url=eng%2Fsetup%2Flinux-ikev2-vpn to install the VPN. Multiple websites mention certificates, but since I am on the client-side, do I need to create certificates? should I configure someting specifically?

Any hint, idea, solution is welcome.

Comment: check the logs on the other end as well

Answer (score 0):

Without detailed log from at least your end it is not possible to be sure what is going on.
However, checking the guide which you referenced in your question, I think I might have spot the issue.

In the step 7 of the guide, there is an instruction to customize cipher proposals to a single specific one. The specific cipher proposal might not be supported by the other end. I suggest to remove this limitation, i.e. to uncheck the checkbox. I took a screenshot of the step 7 from the guide and marked the checkbox with a red arrow, see below.
[image: screenshot]